# How to find all cyclic shifted strings in a given input?

Tags: string, algorithm, language-agnostic

This is a coding exercise. Suppose I have to decide if one string is created by a *cyclic shift* of another. For example: `cab` is a cyclic shift of `abc` but `cba` is not.

Given two strings `s1` and `s2` we can do that as follows:

```
if (s1.length != s2.length)
  return false
for(int i = 0; i < s1.length(); i++)
  if ((s1.substring(i) + s1.substring(0, i)).equals(s2))
    return true
return false
```

Now what if I have an array of strings and want to find all strings that are cyclic shift of one another? For example: `["abc", "xyz", "yzx", "cab", "xxx"] -> ["abc", "cab"], ["xyz", "yzx"], ["xxx"]`

It looks like I have to check *all pairs* of the strings. Is there a "better" (more efficient) way to do that?

Answer (score 7):

As a start, you can know if a string s1 is a rotation of a string s2 with a single call to contains(), like this:

```
public boolean isRotation(String s1, String s2){
    String s2twice = s2+s2;
    return s2twice.contains(s1);
}
```

Namely, if s1 is "rotation" and s2 is "otationr", the concat gives you "otationrotationr", which contains s1 indeed.

Now, even if we assume this is linear, or close to it (which is not impossible using Rabin-Karp, for instance), you are still left with O(n^2) pair comparisons, which may be too much.

What you could do is build an hashtable where the sorted word is the key, and the posting list contains all the words from your list that, if sorted, give the key (ie. key("bca") and key("cab") both should return "abc"):

```
private Map<String, List<String>> index;
    /* ... */
public void buildIndex(String[] words){
    for(String word : words){
        String sortedWord = sortWord(word);
        if(!index.containsKey(sortedWord)){
            index.put(sortedWord, new ArrayList<String>());
        }
        index.get(sortedWord).add(word);
    }
}
```

CAVEAT: The hashtable will contain, for each key, all the words that have exactly the same letters occurring the same amount of times (not just the rotations, ie. "abba" and "baba" will have the same key but isRotation("abba", "baba") will return false).

But once you have built this index, you can significantly reduce the number of pairs you need to consider: if you want all the rotations for "bca" you just need to sort("bca"), look it up in the hashtable, and check (using the isRotation method above, if you want) if the words in the posting list are the result of a rotation or not.

Comment: His question is `language-agnostic`.

Comment: I provided snippets in Java just for sake of example... I used hashtables and strings, I would say the solution is language-agnostic as well, no?

Answer (score 6):

If strings are short compared to the number of strings in the list, you can do significantly better by rotating all strings to some normal form (lexicographic minimum, for example). Then sort lexicographically and find runs of the same string. That's O(n log n), I think... neglecting string lengths. Something to try, maybe.

Answer (score 1):

Concerning the way to find the pairs in the table, there could be many better way, but what I came up as a first thought is to sort the table and apply the check per adjacent pair.

This is much better and simpler that checking every string with every other string in the table

Answer (score 1):

Consider building an automaton for each string against which you wish to test.

Each automaton should have one entry point for each possible character in the string, and transitions for each character, plus an extra transition from the end to the start.

You could improve performance even further if you amalgated the automata.

Answer (score 1):

I think a combination of the answers by Patrick87 and savinos would make a fair amount of sense. Specifically, in a Java-esque pseudo-code:

```
List<String> inputs = ["abc", "xyz", "yzx", "cab", "xxx"];
Map<String,List<String>> uniques = new Map<String,List<String>>();
for(String value : inputs) {
    String normalized = normalize(value);
    if(!uniques.contains(normalized)) {
        unqiues.put(normalized, new List<String>());
    }
    uniques.get(normalized).add(value);
}
// you now have a Map of normalized strings to every string in the input
// that is "equal to" that normalized version
```

Normalizing the string, as stated by Patrick87 might be best done by picking the rotation of the string that results in the lowest lexographic ordering.

**It's worth noting, however, that the "best" algorithm probably relies heavily on the inputs... the number of strings, the length of those string, how many duplicates there are, etc.**

Answer (score 1):

You can rotate all the strings to a normalized form using Booth's algorithm (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographically_minimal_string_rotation) in O(s) time, where s is the length of the string.

You can then use the normalized form as a key in a HashMap (where the value is the set of rotations seen in the input). You can populate this HashMap in a single pass over the data. i.e., for each string

- calculate the normalized form
- check if the HashMap contains the normalized form as a key - if not insert the empty Set at this key
- add the string to the Set in the HashMap

You then just need to output the values of the HashMap. This makes the total runtime of the algorithm O(n * s) - where n is the number of words and s is the average word length. The total space usage is also O(n * s).